# 'DjangoDetailsView' object has no attribute 'object'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to mix `CreateView` and `DetailView` in Django in one View, here is how I did it :

**models.py**

```py
class Supplier(models.Model):
    person_name = models.CharField(max_length=850)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=1200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=2200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('supplier_details', args=[str(self.id)])


class SupplierItem(models.Model):
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=CASCADE)
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('portal_to_supplier', args=[str(self.supplier.id)])
```

**forms.py**

```py
class SupplierItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SupplierItem
        fields = ['item', 'unit_price']
```

**views.py**

```py
class SupplierDetailsView(FormView, DetailView):
    model = Supplier
    form_class = SupplierItemForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SupplierDetailsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        return context


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return FormView.post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The page renders great and the form too, but then I submit the form, it gives me this error :

```
'SupplierDetailsView' object has no attribute 'object'
```

**NOTE**

`object` is used as the object itself in the detail view, I'm rendering it inside the `HTML` as `{{objects.name}}`, it works great in the `GET` but seems like not found in `POST`

**FUll traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/supplier/4/details

Django Version: 3.0.2
Python Version: 3.6.9
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'django_filters',
 'el_pagination',
 'mathfilters',
 'profiture_branches.apps.ProfitureBranchesConfig',
 'profiture_employees.apps.ProfitureEmployeesConfig',
 'profiture_categories.apps.ProfitureCategoriesConfig',
 'profiture_treasury.apps.ProfitureTreasuryConfig',
 'profiture_item.apps.ProfitureItemConfig',
 'profiture_products.apps.ProfitureProductsConfig',
 'profiture_warehouse.apps.ProfitureWarehouseConfig',
 'profiture_invoicing.apps.ProfitureInvoicingConfig',
 'profiture_recipes.apps.ProfitureRecipesConfig',
 'profiture_additions.apps.ProfitureAdditionsConfig',
 'profiture_consumables.apps.ProfitureConsumablesConfig',
 'profiture_supplier.apps.ProfitureSupplierConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ahmed/Documents/projects/Profiture/admin_website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ahmed/Documents/projects/Profiture/admin_website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/ahmed/Documents/projects/Profiture/admin_website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/ahmed/Documents/projects/Profiture/admin_website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ahmed/Documents/projects/Profiture/admin_website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ahmed/Documents/projects/Profiture/admin_website/profiture_supplier/views.py", line 21, in post
    return FormView.post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ahmed/Documents/projects/Profiture/admin_website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 144, in post
    return self.form_invalid(form)
  File "/home/ahmed/Documents/projects/Profiture/admin_website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 61, in form_invalid
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
  File "/home/ahmed/Documents/projects/Profiture/admin_website/profiture_supplier/views.py", line 15, in get_context_data
    context = super(SupplierDetailsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
  File "/home/ahmed/Documents/projects/Profiture/admin_website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 67, in get_context_data
    return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
  File "/home/ahmed/Documents/projects/Profiture/admin_website/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py", line 94, in get_context_data
    if self.object:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /supplier/4/details
Exception Value: 'SupplierDetailsView' object has no attribute 'object'
```

Comment: set `self.object = None` in the `def post` as first line. The `FormView` checks if it is an instance to decide if it is a create/edit view.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem adding `self.object=None` caused the `object` to be None and `{{object.name}}` is not working anymore.

Comment: sorry, `self.object = self.get_object()`.